# Is there a way to login to the server using voice ID when verification happens locally?

Tags: security, authentication, api-design, biometrics

If voiceprint verification happens locally in a mobile app, how would you let the server securely know that the user is verified? I thought about using an API key of sorts, maybe generating a random string and distributing that with the app. So when the user's voice is verified locally, it will tell the server. And because the request included the API key, the server will trust the request and respond with a login token.

That solution is not very convincing though. Is there a way to login using voiceprint when verification happens inside an app?

Comment: Where is the voice verification happening.. I mean the decision if the voice fingerprint is valid or not?

Comment: On a phone app.

Comment: What I want to know is if the decision is made on the device itself or if the fingerprint of the voice is sent to an external service that gives back you an answer saying is valid or invalid?

Comment: It has to be made on the device. We avoid sending voice data to the server for the user's privacy. If someone can steal your password you can just change it. But you can't exactly do the same for your voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## API SERVER CANNOT TRUST IN REQUESTS

> And because the request included the API key, the server will trust the request and respond with a login token.

The API server cannot trust in any request they receive based only in an API key, because they are so easy to extract from a mobile app with reverse engineering tools we can find in the open source community.

In order to better understanding why we cannot blindly trust in requests arriving to the API server we need to understand 2 concepts, **WHO** and **WHAT** is communicating with the API server.

## WHO AND WHAT IS ACCESSING THE API SERVER

The **WHO** is the user of the mobile app that you can authenticate,authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID, OAUTH2 flows or the VoicePrint.

But before you know the **WHO** you need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling your API server and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server, is it really your genuine mobile app or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

Well to identify the **WHAT** developers tend to resort to an API key that usually they hard-code in the code of their mobile app and some go the extra mile and compute it at run-time in the mobile app, thus becomes a dynamic secret in opposition to the former approach that is a static secret embedded in the code.

## REVERSE ENGINEERING A MOBILE APP BINARY IS EASY

> I thought about using an API key of sorts, maybe generating a random string and distributing that with the app.

The truth is that anything running in the client side can be reverse engineered
easily by an attacker on a device he controls. He will use introspection frameworks like [Frida](https://www.frida.re/) or [xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) to intercept at runtime the running code of the mobile app or will use a proxy tool like [MiTM Proxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/) for watching the communications between the mobile app and the API server. Normally their first step in reverse engineer a mobile app will be to use the [Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) to reverse engineer the binary of you mobile app to extract all static secrets, aka the API key, and to identify other attack vectors.

> If voiceprint verification happens locally in a mobile app, how would you let the server securely know that the user is verified?

So doing this verification in the client side opens the vector attack of using XPosed, Frida or even MobSF at runtime for tampering with the results of voice verification.

Remember that users in order to get free Wi-Fi can be tricked to install malware apps or custom ssl certificates, that will allow an attacker to introspect, intercept and modify the decisions being made on the device and manipulating the data being sent over the wire to the API server, by other words they are able to bypass the voiceprint recognition results.

[Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)

> Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

[xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too much). It's also easy to undo.

[MiTM Proxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/)

> An interactive TLS-capable intercepting HTTP proxy for penetration testers and software developers.

## A POSSIBLE SOLUTION

So anything that runs on the client side and that uses some secret to access an API server can be abused, and you can learn more on [this series](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) of articles about Mobile API Security Techniques. This articles will teach you how API Keys, User Access Tokens, HMAC and TLS Pinning can be used to protect the API and how they can be bypassed.

> That solution is not very convincing though.

To solve the problem of **WHAT** is accessing your mobile app you need to use one or all the solutions mentioned in the series of articles about Mobile API Security Techniques that I mentioned above and accepted that they can only make unauthorized access to your API server harder to bypass but not impossible. This means that while harder is still possible to bypass the voiceprint recognition result.

> Is there a way to login using voiceprint when verification happens inside an app?

As I already mentioned previously any decisions made on the device can be tampered with at run-time, thus having the mobile communicating with the API server to login the user based on that decision needs to take in account that it can be manipulated to bypass the voiceprint recognition.

Just to be clear the bypass can happen on the device itself by manipulating at runtime the returned result of the voiceprint verification to be always `true` or by intercepting the communication with the API server and change the result of the voiceprint recognition to be always `true`.

From your comments in the question:

> It has to be made on the device. We avoid sending voice data to the server for the user's privacy. If someone can steal your password you can just change it. But you can't exactly do the same for your voice.

Now that you know that at runtime the voiceprint recognition can be tampered with, the malware doing it can also extract the results and send them back to the attacker, thus compromising is voice fingerprint, that as you correctly said the user cannot change.

Not convinced yet, please give it a read [Biometrics could replace our passwords — 
and there’s actually a big problem with that](https://medium.com/@cyberalterego/biometrics-could-replace-our-passwords-and-theres-actually-a-big-problem-with-that-d32b5a20c8df) where you can read for example:

> But a biometrics breach has even more serious implications. If someone gets ahold of your fingerprints, he can possibly steal your identity.

To help with communicating the voiceprint recognition results to the API server, a Mobile App Attestation solution can be employed. It will enable the API server to know is receiving only requests from a genuine mobile app that is not running in a root or jail broken device, attached to introspection frameworks or in debug mode.

### Mobile App Attestation

Use a Mobile App Attestation solution to enable the API server to know **WHAT** is sending the requests, thus enabling it to only respond to requests from a genuine mobile app.

The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered or is not running in a rooted device by running a SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

Now the App must sent with every API call the JWT token in the headers of the request. This will allow the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

> the server will trust the request and respond with a login token.

So with this solution in place the API server can trust in the mobile app request saying that the voiceprint recognition is valid, thus it can issue a user authentication token to be used in subsequent communications with the API server.

The Mobile App Attestation service already exists as a SAAS solution at Approov(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS, Android, React Native and others. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token issued by the cloud service. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.